# formObject.submit() is not working

Tags: javascript, submit

I have a simple form and I am using javascript for validation of data entered. I can't understand why document.getElementById("submitform").submit() is not working. Below is my code. Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkSyntax(){

jsid=document.getElementById("sid").value;
jname=document.getElementById("name").value;
jemail=document.getElementById("email").value;
jgpa=document.getElementById("gpa").value;

var noError=true;
var Regsig=/^[2][0-9]{8}$/;
var Regn=/^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/;
var Rege=/^[a-zA-Z]+[_]?[a-zA-Z]*[@][a-zA-Z]+[.](net|com|edu.sa)$/;
var Regg=/^[1-4]+[.][0-9]+/;

if(!Regsig.test(jsid)){
    alert("The student ID must be all numbers and of length 9");
    noError=false;
}
if(!Regn.test(jname)){
    alert("Name must be alphabets of min length 3 and max 25");
            noError=false;

}
if(!Rege.test(jemail)){
    alert("Wrong email format");
            noError=false;

}
if(!Regg.test(jgpa)){
    alert("Wrong GPA format");
            noError=false;

}
if(noError){
  **document.getElementById("submitform").submit();**
}
}
function checkRetrieve(Sid2,Name2){
var Regsig=/(|[2][0-9]{8})/;
var Regn=/(|[a-zA-Z]{2,25})/;
var error=true;

if(!Regsig.test(sid.value)){
    alert("The student ID must be all numbers and of length 9");
    error=false;
}
if(!Regn.test(name.value)){
    alert("Name must be alphabets of min length 3 and max 25");
    error=false;
}
if(Sid2.value!="" && Name2.value!=""){
    alert("you can only use on of the two fields for your query");
    Sid2.value="";
    Name2.value="";
    error=false;

}



}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<h1>Web-Based Application for Student Academic Records</h1>
<p> Add a new student</p>
<body>

<form id="submitform" name="form1" method="post" action="stacademic.php">
Student ID:<input type="text" size="26" maxlength="9" name="SID"id="sid"/><br /><br />
Name:<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" name="NAME" id="name"/><br /><br />
Email:<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" name="EMAIL" id="email"/><br /><br />
Major: <select id="major" name="MAJOR">
<option>Computer Engineering<option/>
<option>Computer Science<option/>
<option>Electrical Engineering<option/>
<option>Mechanical Engineering<option/>
<option>Software Engineering<option/>
</select><br />
<br /> 
GPA:<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="5" name="GPA" id="gpa"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="checkSyntax()"  name="submit"/><br />
</form><br /> 


<p> Retrieve student GPA either Student ID or Student Name: </p>
<form id="retrieveform" onSubmit="return checkRetrieve(this.sid2,this.name2);"       method="post" action="stacademic.php">
Student ID:<input type="text" size="26" maxlength="9" name="SID2" id="sid2"/><br /><br />
Name:<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" name="NAME2" id="name2"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Retrieve Results"  name="submit2"/><br />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, the form is already being submitted.

What you should to is to assign the checkSyntax to the onsubmit event and then return true if everything was right or return false if errors occurs. If the function in the onsubmit event returns false, the form is not submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right, your submit button is submitting the form.  You should use the onSubmit event on your form and if validation fails, have it return false, which will cancel the submit.  Also, it is not a good idea to use onclick because if the user submits the form by hitting enter, the function will be bypassed.

```
<form id="submitform" name="form1" method="post" action="stacademic.php" onSubmit="checkSyntax()">
```